# Get coordinates from polyline google maps

Tags: google-maps

This my code

http://jsfiddle.net/6KacA/

everything work fine. i can draw on map but i want get coordinates which is i have drawing on map. how can i do it on api v3?

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 12):

There is a polylinecomplete-event for the drawingManager, observe it to access the polyline(it will be the first argument provided to the callback-function).

Then use `polyline.getPath()` to access the path and work with it using the methods of [MVCArray](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#MVCArray)

[**Example**:](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/B7SWV/)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polylinecomplete', function(line) {
  alert(line.getPath().getArray().toString());
});
```

Comment: How can I achieve this from backend via Node.js? I have a bunch of coordinates 300m apart and I want to know if they lie in the polyline or not..

Answer (score 6):

You can get all the polilynes coordinates with the following function.

```
function getPathVariableCode(line){
var codeStr = '  var linePath = [\n';
var pathArr = line.getPath();
for (var i = 0; i < pathArr.length; i++){
    codeStr += '    {lat: ' + pathArr.getAt(i).lat() + ', lng: ' + pathArr.getAt(i).lng() + '}' ;
    if (i !== pathArr.length-1) {
        codeStr += ',\n';
    };

};

codeStr += '\n  ];';

//the coordinates path it´s print on the console of the browser

console.log (codeStr);
console.log(pathArr.length);

};
```

And this how you call the function

```
 line.addListener('click', function () {
 getPathVariableCode(line);
 });
```

Then you just clic on a point to generate the coordinates on the console browser

------------ HERE IS THE COMPLETE CODE ---------

```js
var map;
function initialize() {

  

    //Map options
   var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.075464, -94.012622),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    scaleControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    draggable: true,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    keyboardShortcuts: false,
 
  }
    //map canvas
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions );
   //coordinates por the polyline
  var linePath = [
    {lat: 18.068652, lng: -94.25055299999997},
    {lat: 16.766951, lng: -93.31531000000001}
  ];
    //Polyline Options
  var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: linePath,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#ff0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.4,
    strokeWeight: 8,
 editable: true // if you dont want to see the editable point change it to false
  });

     //call to the path coordinates function

  line.addListener('click', function () {
     getPathVariableCode(line);
 });
    //set map
 line.setMap(map);
 };

//here we call the initialize function which load the map
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


//function to get all the coordinates of the polyline
function getPathVariableCode(line){
 var codeStr = '  var linePath = [\n';
 var pathArr = line.getPath();
 for (var i = 0; i < pathArr.length; i++){
  codeStr += '    {lat: ' + pathArr.getAt(i).lat() + ', lng: ' + pathArr.getAt(i).lng() + '}' ;
        if (i !== pathArr.length-1) {
   codeStr += ',\n';
  };
       
 };
    
 codeStr += '\n  ];';
    
    //the coordinates path it´s print on the console of the browser

    console.log (codeStr);
    console.log(pathArr.length);
 
};
```

```css
#map_canvas {
    width: 90%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #999;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 



</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Push Wrapper -->
        <div class="mp-pusher" id="mp-pusher">


           
            <!-- /scroller-inner -->

            <div id="map_canvas"></div>

        </div>

        <!-- /pusher -->
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->

    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=drawing"></script>
    

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    myfile.csv:

    -6.9906775;38.0667982
    -6.9906474;38.0666109
    -6.9904324;38.0663124
    ...

    var coordsList= [];
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "myfile.csv",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {                    
                var allTextLines = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
                allTextLines.forEach(function(element) {
                    var entry = element.split(';');
                    coordsList.push({lat: entry[0]*1, lng: entry[1]*1});
                });
                console.log(coordsList);
            }
        });

    var myArea = new google.maps.Polygon({paths: coordsList});
```