# How to get Coordinates from polyline (google maps api)?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am able to draw a polyline between source and destination using google maps API on android. Now, I want to get locations from the polyline for let's say every 25 meter. So, as the polyline is generated between two points, app must generate coordinates for the points on polyline at a distance of 25 meter. So as you can see in image I need coordinates for blue crosses.

Coordinates for blue crosses on the path needed:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019110/get-coordinates-from-polyline-google-maps

Comment: thanks, i will try solutions provided there.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem with help of two approach:

1) In fused location there is a field of displacement of user location, where you can put your desire displacement like 25 meter. After 25 meter you get updated location. Then you can search nearest location using searching filter on polyline location array.

```
mlocationrequest = LocationRequest.create();
mlocationrequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
mlocationrequest.setInterval(60000); // Update location every 1 minute
mlocationrequest.setFastestInterval(10000);
mlocationrequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10);
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.mGoogleApiClient, mlocationrequest, this);
```

2) Other one is whenever you get updated location then you can check difference between your current location and past location. you need to save your last location.

```
Location selected_location=new Location("locationA");
selectedlocation.setLatitude(17.372102);
        selected_location.setLongitude(78.484196);
Location near_locations=new Location("locationB");
        near_locations.setLatitude(17.375775);
        near_locations.setLongitude(78.469218);
double distance=selected_location.distanceTo(near_locations);
```

Comment: i need the coordiantes of the points at the beginning of the journey. I mean as the polyline is generated, it should get the coordiantes of all these points

Comment: Whenever you draw polyline on map then you have to pass source & destination coordinates, so i think source is your current location, so you can easily get current location.